# How can I use ttorrent java library to download separate files from multifile torrent?

Tags: java, torrent

I am trying to use ttorrent in my scala application and one of the cases that I need to download not the whole torrent, but only part of it (one file per folder, for example). There is a Torrent.getFilenames method which gives a list of files inside the torrent, but I cannot see ability to download some of these files. Is there a way or I need to extend the library to do it, cannot find anything in the codebase for now.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with torrents, but what I understand that isn't possible. A torrent needs to downloaded completely in order to access the separate files.

Comment: utorrent is able to do it

Comment: I use utorrent, but never needed/looked for such a functionality. How do you access it?

Comment: well, you open multifile torrent as usual (some old band discography, for example) and standard dialog opens, the right part of the dialog window ("Torrent contents") is a control to select\deselect the whole tree structure of torrent you are going to download. You select the albums you like and it will load only them.